# Javascript / HTML Form Validation Issues

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently having an issue with how my form validates. For simplicity, I am only validating the first and last name for now here.

Let's say one does not enter their first name or their last name. It only shows the error message "(Please Enter Your First Name)" and it doesn't show "(Please Enter Your Last Name)".

Let's say one enters their first name and not their last name, it then shows "(Please Enter Your Last Name)".

Is there a way around this issue so if, for example, someone doesn't enter their first name and their last name it will show both error messages?

JavaScript:

```
function validateAll() {
    //Inputs
    var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value; 
    var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;   

    //Errors
    var firstNameError = document.getElementById("firstNameError");
    var lastNameError = document.getElementById("lastNameError");

    if (
        validateFirstName(firstName, firstNameError) == true &&
        validateLastName(lastName, lastNameError) == true
        ) {
        return true;     
    } else return false;
}   

function validateFirstName(firstName, firstNameError) {
    if (firstName == "") {
        firstNameError.firstChild.nodeValue = "(Please Enter Your First Name)";
        return false;
    } else {
        firstNameError.firstChild.nodeValue = "";
        return true;
    }
}

function validateLastName(lastName, lastNameError) {
    if (lastName == "") {
        lastNameError.firstChild.nodeValue = "(Please Enter Your Last Name)";
        return false;
    } else {
        lastNameError.firstChild.nodeValue = "";
        return true;
    }    
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="registrationForm" id="registrationForm" onSubmit="return validateAll()" action="AddUserDetails">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <span id="firstNameError" class="error">*</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastName">Second Name</label>
        <span id="lastNameError" class="error">*</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
        <span id="phoneNumberError" class="error">*</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="eMail">E-Mail</label>
        <span id="eMailError" class="error">*</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eMail" name="eMail">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="eMailConfirmation">Confirm E-Mail</label>
        <span id="eMailConfirmationError" class="error">*</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eMailConfirmation" name="eMailConfirmation">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <span id="passwordError" class="error">*</span>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-user-md"></i> Register</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of how your code is being evaluated.

```
validateFirstName(firstName, firstNameError) == true &&
validateLastName(lastName, lastNameError) == true
```

It will run the first function and if the first name isn't set it returns false. `false && (true || false)` will **always** be false so it doesn't execute the second function.

As you can see when you run this snippet as soon as it hits a `false` it stop executing (3 is the last number printed). With or it only executes the first function.

```js
function test(bool, num){
  console.log(num);
  return bool;
}

var andResult =   test(true, 1) &&
                  test(true, 2) && 
                  test(false, 3) && 
                  test(true,4);
                  
console.log("&& result", andResult);
                  
var orResult =    test(true, 1) ||
                  test(true, 2) || 
                  test(false, 3) || 
                  test(true,4);                  


console.log("|| result", orResult);
```

You could run each function and collect the values:

```
var valFirstName = validateFirstName(firstName, firstNameError);
var valLastName = validateLastName(lastName, lastNameError);

return valFirstName && valLastName;
```

Comment: Would you suggest I split it up into two if statements or should I do the whole thing in a completely different way?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the way javascript evaluates if statements. Because you are using a &&, if the first condition fails, it doesn't even bother to try execute the second condition because no matter what the outcome the loop will not run ((false && true) == false).
Try console logging some stuff in your validateLastName function and you'll see what i'm talking about ;)

I can't find any further information about all this jazz, but i think C++ compilers do the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

So you're using a logical AND statement, and my downvote was because I used a logical OR statement that was closer, but not quite right. Here's the mini-lecture.

Logical AND expressions will execute each portion of the statement UNTIL the first false is encountered, at which point the entire expression is rendered false and the AND expression is exited. Logical OR statements, on the other hand, will execute each portion of the statement, regardless of truth or falsity, and THEN evaluate the expression's ultimate boolean. So using the AND as you do, the expression stops with the first false. There are two ways of handling this.

First, you can do as has been suggested, and evaluate every validation function to a variable, then use all of those in an AND statement. Doing this ensures that all of your form fields have been validated. Then the AND statement can simply determine if the form is valid or not.

```
var firstNameIsValid = validateFirstName(firstName, firstNameError),
    lastNameIsValid  = validateLastName(lastName, lastNameError);

if (firstNameIsValid && lastNameIsValid){
  // Form is valid, proceed with processing
} else {
  // Form is invalid because SOMETHING above was false. Do some other
  //  error handling.
}
```

Second, which was the road I was on (but not quite close to the correct response) combines that into a single OR statement, but rather than checking if the fields are valid, we're going to check that they're **invalid**.

```
if (!validateFirstName(firstName, firstNameError) || !validateLastName(lastName, lastNameError) ) {
  // The above query is checking whether validate<fieldName> returned FALSE 
  //   for every field. If any validate returns false, the entire form is
  //   invalid. Do any invalid form processing.
} else {
  // The ELSE of the above if would only pass if every form field checked has
  //   in fact, passed the validity check. At this point, the form itself is
  //   valid and any processing for valid forms can happen.
}
```

Now, with all that said, you're creating an ugly morass for yourself down the line. At this point, you only need a valid first name and last name. But what if they contain a number? What if you WANT a field that's only numbers? What if you want a field to be both required, and a telephone number? You're going to have to re-create the wheel for every single case. Instead, how about creating a function that can be generalized to work for every case? If you encounter a case you don't have a handler for, you can create that and add it to the generalized function, making it available to any other form element later.

```js
 var formEl = document.getElementById("my-custom-form");
 formEl.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
     evt.stopPropagation();
     evt.preventDefault();

     var isFormValid = [];
     var validateThese = [{
       fieldEl: formEl.querySelector("[name=firstName]"),
       errorEl: formEl.querySelector("#firstNameError"),
       checks: ["required", "alpha"]
     }, {
       fieldEl: formEl.querySelector("[name=lastName]"),
       errorEl: formEl.querySelector("#lastNameError"),
       checks: ["required", "alpha"]
     }, {
       fieldEl: formEl.querySelector("[name=phoneNumber]"),
       errorEl: formEl.querySelector("#phoneNumberError"),
       checks: ["numeric"]
     }];

     for (var i = 0, len = validateThese.length; i < len; i++) {
       isFormValid[i] = validateField(validateThese[i]);
     }

     if (isFormValid.indexOf(false) != -1) {
       // If there is ANY boolean false here, then one of the fields returned
       //  false, so the whole form is bad.
       console.log("form is bad!");
     } else {
       // The entire isValid array is good, the form is good.
       console.log("form is good!");
     }

     function validateField(checkThis) {
       var isValid = [];
       checkThis.errorEl.innerText = "";

       for (var i = 0, len = checkThis.checks.length; i < len; i++) {
         switch (checkThis.checks[i]) {
           case "required":
             isValid[i] = isRequired(checkThis.fieldEl);
             if (!isValid[i]) {
               checkThis.errorEl.innerHTML += "<br>Field is required!";
             }
             break;
           case "alpha":
             isValid[i] = isAlpha(checkThis.fieldEl);
             if (!isValid[i]) {
               checkThis.errorEl.innerHTML += "<br>Field must be alphabetic characters only!";
             }
             break;
           case "numeric":
             isValid[i] = isNumeric(checkThis.fieldEl);
             if (!isValid[i]) {
               checkThis.errorEl.innerHTML += "<br>Field must be numeric characters only!";
             }
             break;
           case "alphanumeric":
             isValid[i] = isAlphanumeric(checkThis.fieldEl);
             if (!isValid[i]) {
               checkThis.errorEl.innerHTML += "<br>Field must be alphanumeric only!";
             }
             break;
         } // End switch
       } // End for

       if (isValid.indexOf(false) == -1) {
         // isValid contains no false values, this field is ok.
         return true;
       } else {
         // isValid contains at least one false. At least one test failed.
         //  field is bad.
         return false;
       }
     } // End validateField()

     /****
      * Below are the actual validation functions. Given a field, they'll
      *  check that it conforms to a few types. At this pass, it'll look for
      *  required, alphabetic, numeric or alphanumeric.
      *
      ****/

     function isRequired(fieldEl) {
       if (fieldEl.value.length > 0) {
         return true;
       } else {
         return false;
       }
     } // end function isRequired();

     function isAlpha(fieldEl) {
       if (fieldEl.value.length > 0) {
         if (/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(fieldEl.value)) {
           return true;
         } else {
           return false;
         }
       } else {
         return true;
       }
     } // end function isAlpha();

     function isNumeric(fieldEl) {
       if (fieldEl.value.length > 0) {
         if (/^\d+$/.test(fieldEl.value)) {
           return true;
         } else {
           return false;
         }
       } else {
         return true;
       }
     } //end function isNumeric();

     function isAlphanumeric(fieldEl) {
       if (fieldEl.value.length > 0) {
         if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(fieldEl.value)) {
           return true;
         } else {
           return false;
         }
       } else {
         return true;
       }
     } // end function isAlphaumeric();

   }) // end button click event listener
```

```html
<form id="my-custom-form" name="registrationForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <span id="firstNameError" class="error">*</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="required">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lastName">Second Name</label>
    <span id="lastNameError" class="error">*</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="required">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
    <span id="phoneNumberError" class="error"></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="eMail">E-Mail</label>
    <span id="eMailError" class="error"></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eMail" name="eMail">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="eMailConfirmation">Confirm E-Mail</label>
    <span id="eMailConfirmationError" class="error"></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eMailConfirmation" name="eMailConfirmation">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <span id="passwordError" class="error"></span>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-user-md"></i> Register</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

The above example will iterate over an array of objects, each object being a field el, an error el and an array of tests to be run. The "required" test checks that the element's value is greater than zero, and the alpha/numeric/alphanumeric tests return true for either no value or a value matching their regex. These latter three HAVE to return true for no value.

Comment: This will not work either. As soon as it sees the first true it will stop execution. `true || (true || false)` will always be true.

Comment: You're absolutely right. It needs to be checked each time, and set a boolean as false if ANY case is false. I've edited the code to make it so.

Comment: @Aontaigh, take a look at the latest edits -- it incorporates a much more robust system of form-checking, that can be extended easily to accommodate any form.